# How to make your interface to have an array of a given type

Tags: typescript, generics, drop-down-menu, typescript-generics

I am trying to make a generic selector which let's me select multiple options from the values I will provide to it.

```
export interface MyTypeSelector extends Omit<SelectProps, 'children'> {
myTypeArray: MyType[];
onTypeChange?: Function;
modifyBeforeSet?: (value: any) => any;
}
```

I want to give this object as an input to my selector component, and in myTypeArray I want to provide my list. It can be a number array where it holds the ids of all the cities, it can be a string array with Pokemon names for my team, or it can be an array of some random objects I've created.

Should I use something like `any[]` ? In fact I want to restrict the array to have only the same type of objects I will provide during the creation of the selector component. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make `MyTypeSelector` generic and pass the correct type to it when needed:

```
export interface MyTypeSelector<T> extends Omit<SelectProps, 'children'> {
myTypeArray: T[];
onTypeChange?: Function;
modifyBeforeSet?: (value: any) => any;
}
```